# Accuracy by group for fit lda created using caret train function

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret, training-data, resampling

I have created a predictive model using linear discriminant analyses (LDA) and a dataset with four groups Climbing, Ground, Perching, and Predatory. When I use the lda() function of MASS, I know how to use cross-validation to find percent accurately predicted for each group

```
ld=lda(extant.ung,extant.group,CV=TRUE)
ct<-table(extant.group,ld$class)
diag(prop.table(ct,1))
```

where extant.ung is the quantitative data and extant.group is the grouping variable. The above code returns

```
Climbing    Ground  Perching Predatory 
0.7777778 0.8571429 0.6206897 0.9090909
```

However, I would rather use bootstrap resampling techniques from the caret package to find accuracy by group. I have

```
control <- trainControl(method="LGOCV",number=2000)
metric<-"Accuracy"
set.seed(2000)
fit.lda1 <- train(extant.ung,extant.group,method="lda",metric=metric,trControl=control)
fit.lda1
```

So I know how to find total accuracy and Kappa with the above code, but I can't figure out how to find what percent was predicted correctly for each group using this method. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `confusionMatrix` function might be what you are looking for.

**Original Example from question with iris data**

```
library(MASS)
library(caret)
predictors <- iris[1:4]
response <- iris$Species

ld <- lda(predictors, response, CV=TRUE)
ct <- table(response, ld$class)
diag(prop.table(ct,1))

# setosa versicolor  virginica 
# 1.00       0.96       0.98
```

**Applying caret::confusionMatrix()**

```
control <- trainControl(method="LGOCV",number=20)
metric<-"Accuracy"
set.seed(2000)
fit.lda1 <- train(predictors,response,method="lda",metric=metric,trControl=control)
confusionMatrix(fit.lda1)

# Repeated Train/Test Splits Estimated (20 reps, 75%) Confusion Matrix 
# 
# (entries are percentual average cell counts across resamples)
# 
# Reference
# Prediction   setosa versicolor virginica
# setosa       33.3        0.0       0.0
# versicolor    0.0       31.8       0.6
# virginica     0.0        1.5      32.8
# 
# Accuracy (average) : 0.9792
```

**Getting confusionMatrix() data in a friendly format**

I'd also note that if you feed the values and predictions directly in, then `confusionMatrix()` will return data that is more easily manipulated, such as this example.

```
xtab <- confusionMatrix(response, predict(fit.lda1))
as.matrix(xtab)

#            setosa versicolor virginica
# setosa         50          0         0
# versicolor      0         48         2
# virginica       0          1        49
```

Comment: @SavannahCobb glad to hear it.  Perhaps you'd like to accept the answer by click on the checkmark near the top left part of the answer.